# Gravity Form not allowing some file types to upload

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Apologies if this question has been asked earlier.

I'm using the Gravity Forms WordPress plugin and certain file types are not being uploaded

```
**sldprt,stp,step,igs,iges,xt,x_t,dwg,jpg,pdf,catpart,catproduct,rfq**
```

I've added certain file type plugins nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's Wordpress who is preventing you to to upload unknown (dangerous) file types. Here is an example of what I had to do to allow uploading of HEIC images. This code goes in the functions.php file in your theme or in your plugin:

```php
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'add_new_image_mime_types', 1, 1 );
function add_new_image_mime_types( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types['heic'] = 'image/heic';
    return $mime_types;
}

add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'file_and_ext_heic', 10, 4 );
function file_and_ext_heic( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes )
{
    if( false !== strpos( $filename, '.heic' ) )
    {
        $types['ext'] = 'heic';
        $types['type'] = 'image/heic';
    }
    return $types;
}
```